# Angular 5 - getting a lazyloaded module root route inside of its components

Tags: angular, navigation, lazy-loading, router

Is there a way to know the full root route of a lazyloaded module **inside** of it ?

Let's say I have a lazyloaded module called `ParentModule`, and two available routes within: `child1/{id1}` and `child2/{id2}`

Here are my route declarations :

```
// AppRoutingModule

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'parent', loadChildren: './parent/parent.module#ParentModule' },
  ...
];

// ParentRoutingModule

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ParentComponent, children: [
    { path: 'child1/:id1', component: Child1Component},
    { path: 'child2/:id2', component: Child2Component}
  ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

When I am inside the lazyloaded module ParentModule, I don't know about the url that led to it. ParentModule has no clue about the `'/parent'` set upper, inside the AppRoutingModule.

My problem is that I would like to navigate inside the ParentModule (from Parent to childs **AND** from child to child) using a unique command line (in a generic `ParentModule`'s component).

So I expected to use

```
this._router.navigate(['child1', id1], {relativeTo: <?theFamousLazyModuleRootRoute?>});
```

or

```
this._router.navigate([<?theFamousLazyModuleRootRoute?>, 'child1', id1]);
```

But how to know about this root route ?
Does somebody has an idea to dynamically get this info ?

Thanks for any help you could afford.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to navigate inside a lazyloaded module with "local" absolute path is to use the `this._activatedRoute.parent`.

```
this._router.navigate(['child1', id1, {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute.parent})
```

In my case I guess it works because I only have a single level of navigation under the ParentModule route :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ParentComponent, children: [
    { path: 'child1/:id1', component: Child1Component},
    { path: 'child2/:id2', component: Child2Component}
  ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

So I can use `this._activatedRoute.parent` everywhere in the module and reach the root `activatedRoute` of the module.

If you have complex nested routes in your module navigation, this may not work. I did not test.