# How to consistently get the root route of a lazy loaded module in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a lazy load module, where I want to always trigger navigations relative to the module root.

But I can not find a way to consistently find the root route of the module. That is, if my lazy Load module is configured in this way:

```
{
        path: 'my/path/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('@lib/my-module').then((m) => m.MyModule)
```

I want to get something like `my/path/20` so I an always control the module internal routes navigation relative to that path.

Is this possible?

Edit:

I want to get  `my/path/20` even when I am on `my/path/20/children-1/subchildren` etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189897/7365461 Does this help?

Comment: No @AliF50 because I could be in a LazyModule children so the parent could be another that the route of the LazyModule it self